# PHP - Get extension from image URL

Tags: php

I have a URL and i need to grab the extension however in the URL there are addition properties after the extension which varies (height and width)

```
$imageURL = https://digitalcontent.api.tesco.com/v2/media/ghs/be29dc93-727d-499f-b23d-a74a92989ad2/2dc3074e-2142-4625-a91e-29edd9da68bc_711691422.jpeg?h=225&amp;w=225;
$ext = pathinfo($imageURL, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
echo $ext;
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm new to PHP

Thanks
Kevin

```
$ext = pathinfo($imageURL, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$ext2 = preg_replace('/^.*\.([^.]+)$/D', '$1', $imageURL);
echo $ext;
echo $ext2;
```

Comment: URLs don't have "extensions".  What you may be looking for is to send a `HEAD` request to that URL and observe the `Content-Type` header in the response?

Comment: $matches = array();
        $s = preg_match('/\.(\w{3,4})(?:$|\?)/', $imageURL, $matches);
        $fullFilename =  $filename . $matches[0];
        $fullFilename = substr($fullFilename, 0, -1);

Comment: @KevinDeery if you have a suggestion which can work, I'd recommend adding it as an Answer, below. See also [answer]. :-)

Answer (score 2):

First, parse the URL using `parse_url()` to get only the path, without the query parameters. Then, since this particular URL contains something which looks like a file extension in its path, you can use `pathinfo()` as before:

```
$url = "https://digitalcontent.api.tesco.com/v2/media/ghs/be29dc93-727d-499f-b23d-a74a92989ad2/2dc3074e-2142-4625-a91e-29edd9da68bc_711691422.jpeg?h=225&amp;w=225";

$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$ext = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Working demo: https://3v4l.org/gkbaH

More info:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php